# Citrus Framework - Can an API call variable be assigned from a response?

Tags: cucumber, citrus-framework

I want to POST a new object and use one of the fields from the response to map my URI to the correct resourceId. I'm using @variable('resourceId')@ in the path, but it is using the literal URI string to make the request instead of populating with the resourceId from the POST response.

Any idea on a way to get this working? Thank you.

```
Given message itemPostRequestSingle
        And <itemPostRequestSingle> header Content-Type is "application/json;charset=utf-8"
        And <itemPostRequestSingle> header citrus_http_method is "POST"
 -----> And <itemPostRequestSingle> header citrus_request_path is "/path/@variable('resourceId')@/path"
        And <itemPostRequestSingle> payload is
        """

        [
          {
            "relativeId": "${relativeId2}"
          }
        ]

        """

        Given message itemPostResponseSingle
        And <itemPostResponseSingle> header Content-Type is "application/json;charset=utf-8"
        And <itemPostResponseSingle> header citrus_http_status_code is "201"
        And <itemPostResponseSingle> header citrus_http_reason_phrase is "CREATED"
        And <itemPostResponseSingle> payload is

        """
        [
          {
            "relativeId": "${relativeId}"
          },
          {
            "relativeId": "${relativeId2}"
          }
        ]
    """


Scenario: Example
    Given variables
      | relativeId           | citrus:randomString(10,false) |
      | relativeId2          | citrus:randomString(10,false) |

    When <ApiClient> sends message <PostRequest>
    And <ApiClient> should receive Json message <PostResponse>
    And <ApiClient> sends message <itemPostRequestSingle>
    Then <ApiClient> should receive Json message <itemPostResponseSingle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up validation matcher expressions such as `@variable('resourceId')@` and variable references such as `${resourceId}`.

Your `itemPostRequestSingle` should use the variable reference. Your `PostResponse` should use the validation matcher expression in order to extract the id to the variable `resourceId`.

So the idea is to extract the `resourceId` value with a validation matcher expression `@variable('resourceId')@` in order to reference the variable later on in the test case with `${resourceId}`.

Comment: Thank you! I just started using this framework so this is helpful.